# Router.navigate() not working inside functional interceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router, angular-httpclient-interceptors

This is an Angular functional interceptor created to manage possible session timeouts during application usage.

```
export const sessionExpiredInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
    const router: Router = inject(Router);
    return next(req)
        .pipe(
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<never> => {
                if (error.status == 401 && !req.url.includes("login")) {
                    // router.navigateByUrl("/login");
                    window.location.href = '/login';
                }
                return throwError(() => error);
            })
        );
};
```

However, I'm facing an issue with the commented-out line `router.navigateByUrl("/login")`. Whenever this line is executed, an error occurs stating: "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'."

The 'login' route is indeed defined in the application.

Initially, I suspected a context problem. However, after inspecting the code, I confirmed that the router is correctly defined, and I'm using arrow functions, which should preserve the context.

Comment: Why the down vote? Why no single word on what's so wrong? Why this toxic behavior. This is why some users are afraid to ask more questions. Really unecessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as well. Do you have imported the Router in your standalone component like this as example:

**Note:** You can import RouterLink, RouterLinkActive and so on.. You don't need to import the complete `RouterModule`, but you can.

```
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, MytestComponent],
```

*MytestComponent* is the component which is registered in the routes:

```
bootstrapApplication(App,{
  providers: [provideHttpClient(  withInterceptors([sessionExpiredInterceptor])),
  provideRouter([{path: "", pathMatch: "full", component: App}, {path: "test", pathMatch: "full", component: MytestComponent}])]});
```

Thats important, too. Add the routes, all imports and your interceptor into your app.

Last but not least:

```
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

`router-outlet` is important in your html part. With all this Your app will working.

Comment: In deed I had all that in place, something was not working properly and I dont know what. Today I started up the app, I was going to check your answer and voila it was working. I just uncomented the problematic line. Any way thank you for your reply and your time, appreciate it mate!